# Jquery:Copyting content from table to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to copy content of table into a div, and can't make it work...

Here is sample code of the table and div

```
<table><tr>
    <td class="movr">See this content</td>
</tr></table>
<div class="sample"></div>
```

and here is jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var move = $(".movr").html;
$(".sample").html(move);
});
```

Can't find the mistake..

Comment: `html` is a method, not a property. Invoke it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`html` is method and not property. Use `.html()` instead of `.html`:

```
var move = $(".movr").html();
```

Comment: yeah. that was the mistake in this case. Thanks! However, in the original problem, turned out that content wouldn't copy because of numbers in var. Do you know how come?

Comment: @whaaaaaaz: i am not getting what are you saying.

Comment: For some reason, jquery wouldn't give the var the value from table, if var had numbers in the end. Let's say var move = $(".movr").html(); works, and var move22 = $(".movr").html(); doesn't. I've replaced all the numbers, and script is working. Just wondering how come

Answer (score -1):

`$(".movr")` returns an array NOT an object, mate.

Comment: Not true, it returns a jQuery collection. Definitely not an array.